# Crait vs. Krayt

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Upon hearing

> the resistance shuttles would be heading to an old rebel base on

Crait I thought "Oh boy Krayt Dragons!"

> Alas no Krayt Dragons

Is there any in universe explanation for the use of these homophones? I assume they also have the word crate in galactic basic. It seems a bit confusing unless there is some relation. For that matter any directorial or script writing reasons for the use of these similar sounding words would be helpful.

Comment: Ran out of words

Comment: Because there are only so many syllables in the world

Comment: I'm not sure why the down votes. You've got Banthas and Bothans and Tatooine and Dantooine but at least they are a bit different. It makes sense that two one syllable words that sound exactly the same might have an explanation as to why they were used.

Comment: Cassian Andor sounds a lot like Calrissian Endor. It's almost like they do this on purpose

Comment: They got both names out of a crate

Comment: @Valorum only so many syllables in a Galaxy far, far away?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either. I'm skeptical of assuming that the homophones and near-homophones in recent Star Wars names are meant to be explicit references. But either there is a connection or there isn't - the answer may well be "neither any canon story nor the film's writer/director have explained this" and that's fine.

Comment: @recognizer Thanks. I thought the question was clear and useful. I looked it up to make sure its not a duplicate and researched it on Star Wars official site and Wookiepedia so I did some research. I just don't know the answer. I would accept the "not explained" answer if that is what the community comes up with. This universe brought us Dagobah, Sheev Palpatine, and Salacious Crumb the Kowakian monkey-lizard so I thought asking if there was be a reason they are using two different spellings of a word pronounced KRATE was a good question. Maybe they are bummed there were no Krayt dragons too.

Comment: Whatever the reason, I like it when stories do this. Same with multiple characters with the same/similar names. Does it have the potential to be confusing to the audience? Sure, but so does real language, and so it adds to the world-building aspect (as well as causing you to wonder at whether the two words have some common source).

Answer (score 7):

## It's likely that the *origins* of the names were from languages other than Basic, where the word "crate" wouldn't be confusing.

The rebel base on Crait is built in an abandoned mine. I'd guess that the species that built the mine also named the planet.

Krayt dragons are native to Tatooine, a planet monopolized by the Hutts and the Sand People. The name "Krayt" likely came from either Huttese or Tusken.

Comment: I like theory that the names probably come from languages other than Basic. I would posit that Krayt came from Tusken not Huttese since the Sand People were there longer and probably had more interactions with the Krayt dragons.